# Is that possible to make basic_ostream working without facet?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

Might be Visual C++ related only.

While I'm working on a program which running with multiple threads, each works with std::ostream heavily, mainly like:

```
for (auto& work: works)
{
    threadVec.push_back(new thread([work](){working(work);}))
}
void working(Work work)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto& task:work)
    {
        // massive done here
        ss << 1u << 2.0 << "str" << task.GetID();
    }
}
```

Once running, most threads stuck at CRT function `_lock_locales()`, and the thread stack looks like:

```
ntdll!<address>()
program.exe!__acrt_lock()
program.exe!_lock_locales()
......
program.exe!std::use_facet()
......
program.exe!std::basic_ostream<>::operator << (int _Val)
```

My question is: is it possible to avoid using this lock (equals to avoid using facet imo), making each thread work faster?

Not good at english though, giant thanks for any help.

Comment: it looks more like a quaility of service issue with your c++ runtime than a question of the c++ standard.